# Best approach to get drill-down effect states => congressional districts

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I currently have a map that shows state polygons for the US. I would
like to be able to have a user double click a state and then zoom into
the state and show congressional district (CD) polygons.

I have the individual maps working great using kml. Im not sure what's
the best approach for the drill-down from state to CD. The tricky bit is I need the state name/code as thats how I now what KML to generate at the CD level.

I am using google maps api v3.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm getting this wrong, but you want to be able to double click on a point in the map and find out what state that is clicked? Then zoom to that state and display a CD map?

Assuming this to be the case - do a [reverse geocode](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding) in Google Maps on the double click event. From the resulting geographic data you extract the state (the second last data in the results array).

Example response from Google documentation:

```
results[0].formatted_address: "275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
results[1].formatted_address: "Williamsburg, NY, USA",
results[2].formatted_address: "New York 11211, USA",
results[3].formatted_address: "Kings, New York, USA",
results[4].formatted_address: "Brooklyn, New York, USA",
results[5].formatted_address: "New York, New York, USA",
results[6].formatted_address: "New York, USA", // The state information
results[7].formatted_address: "United States"
```

If you then would want to zoom to a predefined state map extent, you could either define your own or use standard geocoding to find the coordinates for the state.

Comment: Thanks for an answer -- I think the other side of the challenge would be how to figure out which CD you are in as the reverse geocoding doesn't have any ability to do that. As well as how to load the CD overlay properly.

Comment: I wonder if this website would provide any assistance with that: http://www.govtrack.us/embed/googlemaps.xpd

Answer (score 0):

Here's the image:

[image: Map of USA]

And here's the source:

```
<img class="map" src="/images/map_us_outline.png" width="550" height="375" usemap="#usa">
<map name="usa">
<area
href="/state.php?state=Washington" title="WA" shape="poly" coords="27,3,27,13,27,28,26,34,33,35,34,42,56,47,77,50,88,49,96,12,48,1,49,12,41,10" />
<area shape="poly" coords="26,32,22,45,13,65,8,73,7,84,28,90,64,100,75,102,83,77,83,68,90,56,88,52,77,49,51,46,36,43,33,35"
href="/state.php?state=Oregon"
alt="Oregon" title="Oregon" />
<area shape="poly" coords="8,85,6,93,2,102,1,111,2,120,3,129,8,143,9,154,10,166,17,186,27,196,44,212,48,222,73,227,76,220,82,210,82,202,74,186,38,134,47,97"
href="/state.php?state=California"
alt="California" title="California"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="96,13,88,50,91,57,82,68,82,76,75,101,133,113,137,79,126,78,118,71,115,61,110,62,111,57,113,50,103,29,104,15"
href="/state.php?state=Idaho"
alt="Idaho" title="Idaho"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="48,97,38,134,81,201,81,188,83,182,89,182,105,109"
href="/state.php?state=Nevada"
alt="Nevada" title="Nevada"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="105,109,93,172,142,182,149,128,129,125,133,113"
href="/state.php?state=Utah"
alt="Utah" title="Utah"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="92,174,88,185,84,183,80,196,84,208,76,218,76,226,72,230,111,253,133,257,143,182"
href="/state.php?state=Arizona"
alt="Arizona" title="Arizona"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="104,16,104,34,113,49,109,61,115,62,118,73,131,78,139,75,204,82,208,30"
href="/state.php?state=Montana"
alt="Montana" title="Montana"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="140,75,132,125,198,134,204,83"
href="/state.php?state=Wyoming"
alt="Wyoming" title="Wyoming"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="151,130,143,180,216,188,220,136"
href="/state.php?state=Colorado"
alt="Colorado" title="Colorado"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="145,182,133,255,142,257,144,250,161,252,163,250,199,253,206,189"
href="/state.php?state=New Mexico"
alt="New Mexico" title="New Mexico"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="208,30,206,68,274,72,267,32"
href="/state.php?state=North Dakota"
alt="North Dakota" title="North Dakota"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="206,69,203,109,254,111,265,115,274,119,276,82,271,78,272,72"
href="/state.php?state=South Dakota"
alt="South Dakota" title="South Dakota"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="202,109,200,134,218,138,219,150,287,152,282,143,274,117,265,114,259,113,250,110"
href="/state.php?state=Nebraska"
alt="Nebraska" title="Nebraska"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="220,149,217,189,294,191,293,161,289,157,288,152,282,150"
href="/state.php?state=Kansas"
alt="Kansas" title="Kansas"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="206,189,206,195,236,197,237,223,257,231,277,235,288,234,297,236,294,192,290,191"
href="/state.php?state=Oklahoma"
alt="Oklahoma" title="Oklahoma"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="206,195,200,253,162,251,165,258,178,273,182,282,197,293,203,283,221,289,237,314,246,330,265,335,263,319,275,302,304,287,306,267,301,246,300,236,289,232,265,231,244,225,238,222,236,197"
href="/state.php?state=Texas"
alt="Texas" title="Texas"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="269,33,274,70,272,77,275,84,276,107,324,103,324,96,313,88,308,79,310,70,318,56,336,44,323,41,311,38,296,36,290,29,285,30"
href="/state.php?state=Minnesota"
alt="Minnesota" title="Minnesota"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="274,105,274,116,282,142,326,144,329,134,328,130,337,122,330,113,325,106,322,103"
href="/state.php?state=Iowa"
alt="Iowa" title="Iowa"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="283,143,292,162,295,181,294,197,340,197,340,203,348,196,349,188,338,172,340,165,333,162,325,152,324,143"
href="/state.php?state=Missouri"
alt="Missouri" title="Missouri"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="295,197,295,234,300,239,302,244,333,243,333,232,341,215,346,204,340,201,341,197,337,196"
href="/state.php?state=Arkansas"
alt="Arkansas" title="Arkansas"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="301,243,304,261,307,270,302,287,321,287,327,284,341,291,349,289,360,292,356,287,357,280,352,278,349,269,329,266,335,249,332,241"
href="/state.php?state=Louisiana"
alt="Louisiana" title="Louisiana"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="314,62,309,76,310,87,323,96,326,108,331,117,357,114,358,99,362,78,356,82,356,74,341,66,327,61,323,58"
href="/state.php?state=Wisconsin"
alt="Wisconsin" title="Wisconsin"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="333,116,337,123,331,130,329,134,325,146,331,159,339,161,340,173,347,183,356,184,364,170,363,137,359,120,356,116"
href="/state.php?state=Illinois"
alt="Illinois" title="Illinois"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="352,185,349,193,367,192,408,188,423,173,415,161,408,159,394,156,389,163,380,172,366,176,361,177"
href="/state.php?state=Kentucky"
alt="Kentucky" title="Kentucky"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="349,194,342,214,400,211,408,201,422,194,429,184,373,191,364,191"
href="/state.php?state=Tennessee"
alt="Tennessee" title="Tennessee"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="340,216,334,226,332,235,335,250,329,264,336,269,349,267,353,275,365,274,363,214"
href="/state.php?state=Mississippi"
alt="Mississippi" title="Mississippi"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="364,213,363,255,365,273,377,274,373,266,402,263,403,244,391,212"
href="/state.php?state=Alabama"
alt="Alabama" title="Alabama"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="391,211,402,244,404,263,438,266,439,260,446,242,423,216,413,207"
href="/state.php?state=Georgia"
alt="Georgia" title="Georgia"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="374,266,378,273,390,273,397,277,407,278,418,275,430,280,432,298,444,316,459,328,470,328,469,310,458,283,449,268,442,260,435,260,433,264,422,264,404,265,399,261"
href="/state.php?state=Florida"
alt="Florida" title="Florida"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="416,208,417,213,433,226,447,245,462,225,470,214,453,204,442,206,439,202,428,202"
href="/state.php?state=South Carolina"
alt="South Carolina" title="South Carolina"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="428,185,415,197,402,205,407,209,424,204,439,202,456,205,471,215,487,202,492,185,488,175"
href="/state.php?state=North Carolina"
alt="North Carolina" title="North Carolina"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="422,174,412,186,444,184,487,175,487,169,482,167,480,157,474,153,470,148,465,142,458,143,453,150,447,154,442,167,434,173"
href="/state.php?state=Virginia"
alt="Virginia" title="Virginia"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="327,60,337,66,352,71,355,82,360,73,376,66,392,64,384,57,377,55,367,58,357,58,351,55,351,49,341,53"
href="/state.php?state=Michigan"
alt="Michigan" title="Michigan"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="382,68,378,77,371,84,368,95,372,112,368,124,388,121,401,120,409,103,405,89,401,90,395,96,393,88,398,72"
href="/state.php?state=Michigan"
alt="Michigan" title="Michigan"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="363,125,364,154,361,172,370,173,386,166,394,157,388,121"
href="/state.php?state=Indiana"
alt="Indiana" title="Indiana"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="389,122,393,156,409,160,418,161,426,149,433,140,430,113,419,120,410,122,404,121,401,119"
href="/state.php?state=Ohio"
alt="Ohio" title="Ohio" />
<area shape="poly" coords="431,136,430,144,422,150,416,159,420,168,429,175,439,169,445,158,449,154,456,144,462,142,458,140,451,143,445,145,442,141,437,142"
href="/state.php?state=West Virginia"
alt="West Virginia" title="West Virginia"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="430,112,434,141,486,131,489,125,484,119,486,107,479,102,455,108"
href="/state.php?state=Pennsylvania"
alt="Pennsylvania" title="Pennsylvania"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="441,92,441,100,434,107,454,107,477,102,487,109,499,112,497,95,494,74,489,65,489,59,477,59,468,69,463,80,459,87"
href="/state.php?state=New York"
alt="New York" title="New York"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="445,139,448,145,459,138,468,142,472,154,480,155,487,150,478,142,481,134,470,134"
href="/state.php?state=Maryland"
alt="Maryland" title="Maryland"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="507,153,507,164,525,164,525,153"
href="/state.php?state=Maryland"
alt="Maryland" title="Maryland"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="507,138,507,149,525,149,525,138"
href="/state.php?state=Delaware"
alt="Delaware" title="Delaware"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="507,122,507,133,525,133,525,122"
href="/state.php?state=New Jersey"
alt="New Jersey" title="New Jersey"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="520,108,520,119,538,119,538,108"
href="/state.php?state=Connecticut"
alt="Connecticut" title="Connecticut"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="530,93,530,104,548,104,548,93"
href="/state.php?state=Rhode Island"
alt="Rhode Island" title="Rhode Island"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="528,77,528,88,546,88,546,77"
href="/state.php?state=Massachusetts"
alt="Massachusetts" title="Massachusetts"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="463,45,463,56,481,56,481,45"
href="/state.php?state=Vermont"
alt="Vermont" title="Vermont"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="484,31,484,42,502,42,502,31"
href="/state.php?state=New Hampshire"
alt="New Hampshire" title="New Hampshire"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="506,50,520,80,527,65,545,49,544,42,535,33,529,16,523,16,516,19,515,31,511,42"
href="/state.php?state=Maine"
alt="Maine" title="Maine"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="52,249,42,253,37,260,31,265,32,270,39,276,39,285,32,281,22,282,26,292,37,294,39,302,30,305,27,313,28,324,39,329,48,337,43,348,33,356,21,360,7,364,12,369,33,362,48,353,59,343,68,333,78,327,85,321,105,321,131,332,147,344,158,340,154,329,141,324,130,316,114,312,107,303,99,271,92,253,84,250,66,250"
href="/state.php?state=Alaska"
alt="Alaska" title="Alaska"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="147,290,145,298,153,297,165,300,170,308,185,312,187,323,197,331,207,325,201,316,192,306,184,299,171,294,161,288,151,288"
href="/state.php?state=Hawaii"
alt="Hawaii" title="Hawaii"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="487,110,485,115,489,125,488,130,484,132,491,137,497,134,497,123,494,117"
href="/state.php?state=New Jersey"
alt="New Jersey" title="New Jersey"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="490,59,492,73,497,86,502,80,504,63,504,55"
href="/state.php?state=Vermont"
alt="Vermont" title="Vermont"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="506,51,505,61,503,74,502,86,513,83,519,80,512,67"
href="/state.php?state=New Hampshire"
alt="New Hampshire" title="New Hampshire"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="497,88,498,97,516,93,524,95,529,91,522,87,519,83,511,83"
href="/state.php?state=Massachusetts"
alt="Massachusetts" title="Massachusetts"   />
<area shape="rect" coords="548,373,550,375"
href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_812073229"
alt="Image Map" title="Image Map" />
</map>
```